# Estamos abertos a aceitar perguntas sobre vocábulos ou traduções sem exemplos claros?

Tags: discussion

Coloco esta perguntar depois de ler:

- [Palavra portuguesa para ''Quantile'' (Eng.)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3664/palavra-portuguesa-para-quantile-eng)
- [Como digo “zoom” em português?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3661/como-digo-zoom-em-portugu%C3%AAs)
- [Qual a diferença entre curtir e perar?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3660/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-curtir-e-perar)

Uma premissa básica é que um signo é a relação entre um significante e um significado. É isto que dá a riqueza da língua, uma vez que as mesmas palavras (signos) podem ter muito diferentes significados dependendo do contexto em que estão envolvidas.

Quando eu pergunto algo tão simples como "*de que maneira eu devo traduzir cadeira pra o inglês*, a minha tendência natural seria responder "chair" mas [cadeira](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/cadeira) também pode ser, por exemplo, uma "*disciplina que se ensina numa aula*".

A resposta que eu daria resultaria em algo como "*The chair I'm attending in college is Programming Level I", claramente o que não se quer. O mesmo acontece com o exemplo "*curtir*" vs "*perar*".

Curtir pode ser "*ficar*" no sentido de "*romance*" e perar... Nem sei o que pode ser perar, para ser sincero mas chutaria "*esperar*", o que não tem sentido em relação à primeira palavra.

Então começam os comentários e os troca-comentários a pedir mais esclarecimentos, etc...

Na minha opinião, este tipo de perguntas com tags como [expressões](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/express%c3%b5es), [estrangeirismos](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estrangeirismos) não deveriam ser aceites sem um exemplo claro na pergunta que permitisse perceber o sentido.

**Exemplo**:

> Na frase "*When you zoom in you take a crop of a portion of the scene
>   and make it take up the whole image.*", eu traduziria zoom como
>   aproximar. No entanto, não tenho certeza sobre esta tradução, pois
>   mesmo usando ferramentas de edição de imagens em português, o termo
>   estrangeiro é adotado.

Ou

> Tomando como exemplo as frases "*O gajo curtiu com a rapariga no
>   carro.*" e "*O cara perou a mina no carro.*", não consego entender
>   qual a diferença entre curtir e perar. Sempre pensei que fossem a
>   mesma coisa mas afinal não.

Daí pergunto, estamos abertos a aceitar perguntas sobre vocábulos ou traduções sem exemplos claros ou deve-se exigir que as mesmas sejam editadas e os mesmos adicionados?

Comment: Eduardo concordo contigo a 100 porcento, é necessário contexto nesse tipo de perguntas, senão mais vale fechar. Eu não as fecho porque não quero impor a minha vontade como moderador, mas se valesse só como um voto, de certeza que votava para fechar até que editassem a pergunta. Atenção que eu não me estou a referir a nenhuma das perguntas em particular, mas sim nesse tipo de perguntas no geral.

Comment: @JorgeB. Mas tu tens o poder de colocar a pergunta "on hold" e pedir ao OP que a refaça acrescentando aquilo que tu consideras estar faltando.   Se ele não o fizer num prazo estipulado por ti, então fecharias a pergunta..  O  moderador não deve se preocupar com o fato de estar ou não "impondo sua vontade", mas sim em fazer aquilo que realmente acredita ser a melhor conduta de acordo com o regulamento geral do SE.

Comment: @Centaurus aconselho que dê uma lida nisto: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/

Comment: @JorgeB Caberia ainda uma lida nisso: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Já que existe uma generalização sobre as ações do moderador (embora o artigo seja de 2009 e talvez precise de atualizações), também seria legal seguir essas diretrizes, o que não está sendo seguido na prática, na minha opinião, quando aceitamos perguntas como tradução de *let's *e *razor blade* (esta última respondida por mim, inclusive).

Comment: @eightShirt a pergunta não tem um voto sequer para fechar, porque é que eu a fecharia? Se a comunidade aceita bem esse tipo de questões quem sou eu pra discordar? Além disso e como opinião pessoal não me parece um simples pedido de tradução. Até porque o autor da pergunta sabe o significado.

Comment: @JorgeB. eu não falei em fechar. Falei que não está sendo seguido na prática. Quantos usuários nós temos que podem pedir closevote? Uma questão que citei não tem sugestão alguma. A outra tem as sugestões, mas uma simples pesquisa, na minha opinião, já ajudaria.

Comment: Uma pergunta minha está sendo questionada neste tópico, por exemplo. E você pode não ter recebido pedido de closevote porque os membros que não gostaram não têm reputação para isso. E mais: nós vamos pela comunidade ou pelas diretrizes sugeridas do SE? Você foi questionado por um membro da comunidade, aí citou as diretrizes. Eu citei diretrizes, você argumentou que a comunidade aceita. Quanto mais claro isso estiver, melhor para todos...

Comment: @eightShirt só são necessários [250 pontos](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/218708) para fechar uma pergunta. As directrizes sugeridas pela SE são mesmo essas, a de me [abster o máximo possível](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators): "A lot of the moderation work is mundane: deleting obvious spam, closing **blatantly** off-topic questions, and culling some of the worst-rated posts on the site. **The ideal moderator does as little as possible**, but those little actions may be powerful, visible, and highly concentrated.".

Comment: @eightShirt se achar que alguma pergunta merece discussão, seja porque motivo for, pode abrir aqui uma discussão no meta sobre o assunto, é para isso que o meta serve, para que a comunidade possa discutir os assuntos do site principal.

Answer (score 1):

Na minha opinião, não.
Não devemos estar abertos a aceitar perguntas sobre vocábulos ou traduções **sem exemplos**, e devemos exigir que as mesmas sejam editadas e os exemplos adicionados.

Mas o *on-topic* e *off-topic* não é uma questão preta-e-branca, é uma escala de cinzentos.

Comment: Mas a questão é mesmo sobre a exigência ou não dos exemplos para contextualizar.

Comment: @EduardoFernandes E eu disse que não quero aceitar essas perguntas, quando não tenham exemplos. Não percebo como a minha resposta pode não responder à pergunta. Podes clarificar?